# If number of application instances > k8s replicas, Redis breaks

Tags: kubernetes, redis

We have Kubernetes setup with 2 replicas and we've noticed that opening any additional instances of the application breaks the application for 1 of the users, and we've narrowed the problem down to Redis.

For example,
If K8s has 1 replica, 2 simultaneous users will break the connection
If K8s has 2 replicas, 3 simultaneous users will break the connection
Etc...

What I'm *thinking* is each pod/replica gets 1 connection to Redis, and once more than 1 user connects to  a single pod then it disconnects the previous user's connection to Redis.

Kube Node settings:

Shards: 1

Multi-AZ: disabled

Number of Nodes: 1 node

Auto-failover: disabled

Our app adds Redis as a singleton, if that makes any difference.
Redis Config:

```
    redisConfig.AsyncTimeout = 3000;
    redisConfig.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
    redisConfig.ClientName = "Fuse-User";
    redisConfig.ReconnectRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(2500);
```

I've also tried making the connection multiplexer "Lazy", but I still think the issue lies with the way Redis is working with Kubernetes.

YAML Script

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dev-app-deployment
  namespace: development
  labels:
    environment: development
spec:
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      environment: development
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: development
      labels:
        environment: development
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dev-app-pod
        image: '$(ecrURL)/$(imageName):$(tag)'
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      nodeSelector:
        environment: development
```

Comment: is it possible to share the yaml how you are setting the redis i have never faced this type of isue.

Comment: The Redis connection happens through the hosted application and there's no configuring happening in the yaml scripts - do I need to define Redis behavior in yaml? Yaml added to main post